# How to use an ACF taxonomy relationship field as part of the URL structure for a custom post type?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, rewrite-rules

I am working on a simple custom post type with several custom taxonomies.  Using ACF I have created fields where the user can select a single value for each of the custom taxonomies.

Here is my custom post type and custom taxonomy.

```
add_action('init', 'pj_product_opt');
function pj_product_opt() {
        register_post_type( 'product', array(
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => 'Products',
                        'singular_name' => 'Product'
                ),
                'description' => 'Products',
                'public' => true,
                'menu_position' => 20,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields'),
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-album'
        ));

        register_taxonomy(
                'product_manufacturer',
                'product',
                array(
                        'labels' => array(
                                'name' => __( 'Manufacturers'),
                                'singular_name' => __('Manufacturer'),
                                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Manufacturer'),
                                'edit_item' => __('Edit Manufacturer'),
                                'new_item' => __('New Manufacturer'),
                                'search_items' => __('Search Manufacturers')
                        ),
                        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product_manufacturer'),
                        'hierarchical' => false
                )
        );
```

I am trying to achieve URLs like the following:
/products/%manufacturer-slug%/%product-slug%

Remember - the value for the manufacturer field is currently in a custom field I have defined and assigned to the `product` post type.  Anything similar to that allowing manufacturers appear as part of the hierarchy would be great.  Any advice would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stupid question, but have you tried creating the Custom Taxonomies using the GUI via the plugin?

I only ask because I recently had problems creating custom taxonomies for a restaurant website via php functions. I could only get it to work if I used the GUI.